# Undefined constant "XML_PI_NODE" symfony

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, apt

My symfony-react project was working. But I wanted to switch to typescript. And made some changes. Then i cleaned my apt list. Made apt autoremove, autoclean, etc.

And when i completely switched from js to ts, i found that my api symfony won't work.
I went for /_profiler, and got this error :

```
Undefined constant "XML_PI_NODE"
```

I already tried to "sudo apt install php8.2-xml", but it still doesnt work.

I think it might be caused by my careless work with apt repo. And i can just reinstall my Ubuntu.) But I want to do this without kill everything.

Ubuntu: 20.04.5 LTS

PHP : 8.2.1

Symfony: 6.0.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused that I had version of php8.2, and removed some packages
via `sudo apt autoclean` and `sudo apt autoremove` from version php8.1(what i forgot), but my nginx configuration was

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;`

Then i just changed it to
`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;`

and all works

Answer (score 0):

I added a .php-version file in the project directory with the previous version (8.2.0 for me) and the problem disapeared.

Write this only in the file :

```
8.2.0 (replace with your version)
```